# Custom User Fields Not Displaying

Tags: 7, users

I've created a couple custom fields for Users in Drupal 7 via Config > Account Settings > Manage Fields. Mainly a user's real name, company and a welcome message.

I'd like this info to be displayed when the user views their account page (site.com/user/username) but the fields will not display except to my admin account. The fields are set to visible in the display settings and the users are assigned the appropriate permissions to view profiles and other content.

I've tried enabling Profile2 and using it as well but the problem still persists. Any ideas what's going on here? It's driving my crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was one of the custom fields. I had added an Organic Groups reference so I could relate that user to a particular group or groups at the time of registration. But for some reason this field's presence was causing the others to not render. This opens up an entirely different issue and will make me rethink how I implement this groups relationship.

Comment: I know it's a long time ago, but did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem now. The custom field show up right on the register user page, but they don't show up on the edit user page :/

Comment: I have added a right solution for it in the answers part.

Answer (score 4):

There is a check box on field edit page of user account which enable "Display on user registration form.". This one might work for you.

Comment: Oh yes, it's there and I'm using it so when I create accounts I can populate that data. The problem is not the form but the actual display of the data on the page. It's not being rendered out.

Answer (score 2):

Just go into the *admin settings(or configuration)*, *OG permissions overview* and check the permission for each custom field.

The *OG permissions overview* can also be reached by: /admin/config/group/permissions

reference: https://www.drupal.org/node/1871428